# Does The Update Column In A Trigger Also Work During An Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am creating a trigger that performs some functionality during an insert or update on a certain column.  I know the below will work for an update, but will it also work for an insert?

```
IF UPDATE (MobilePhone)
BEGIN
SELECT  @TeamId = TeamId FROM Inserted
END
```

Comment: It takes about 5 minutes to write a little test for that...

Comment: HOwever, it is irresponsible to assume inserted will have only one record. NEVER set any value from inserted to a scalar variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can from the MSDN documentation.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx

```
Is the name of the column to test for either an INSERT or UPDATE action. Because the table name is specified in the ON clause of the trigger, do not include the table name before the column name. The column can be of any data type supported by SQL Server. However, computed columns cannot be used in this context.
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work syntactically, but it might not behave the way you want. For INSERT statements the UPDATE(*column*) function always returns TRUE. From the documentation:

> IF UPDATE returns the TRUE value in INSERT actions because the columns have either explicit values or implicit (NULL) values inserted.